# Ruby: metaprogramming methods based in model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, metaprogramming

I'm trying to expose some methods to a class based on the values in its order attribute, which can be something like `['top', 'bottom', 'right', 'lower-right']`.

First, my class deletes from that array anything that responds blank like so:

```
def order
  order.split(' ').delete_if do |o|
    send(o).blank? if respond_to? o
  end
end
```

After that, I want to "expose" `top` (for example's sake) as a method for the class. I've tried stuff like this in the `initialize` method:

```
order.each do |o|
  V1_ATTRIBUTES << o.to_sym
  define_method(o) do |a|
    send(a).blank? ? '' : send(a)
  end
end
```

But `o` isn't defined when the class isn't instantialised, a la:

```
<NameError: undefined local variable or method `o' for #<Class:#<APIDocument:0x007fb8123609f8>>>
```

Anyone have any success with a better way to get this result?

**Note:** I know it's not great practice allowing the user to write instance method names, but in this case security and breakages aren't a concern.

Comment: Is there an infinite recursion in the implementation of the method `order`?

Comment: No, it was simplified for this post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define singleton methods (per-object methods).

```
def order
  orders.split(' ').map{|o| send(o)}.compact.each do |o| 
    singleton_class.send(:define_method, o) do
      send(o).to_s
    end
  end
end
```

But as you can see, this only messes up your code. So don't abuse metaprogramming, use it wisely.

Comment: Ah! Singleton methods. Thank-you!